# Using SkipTo correctly

Tags: python, pyparsing

I've used pyparsing in the past but only for small tasks, this time I'm trying to use it for something more complicated.

I'm trying to skip over a VHDL architecture block, which looks like this

```
architecture Behav of Counter is
  ...many statements I'm not interested in at this point...
end architecture;
```

Here's what I tried:

```
import pyparsing as pp
pp_identifier = pp.Regex(r'([a-zA-Z_][\w]*)')('identifier')
def Keyword(matchString):
    'VHDL keywords are caseless and consist only of alphas'
    return pp.Keyword(matchString, identChars=pp.alphas, caseless=True)

pp_architecture = (
    Keyword('architecture')
    + pp_identifier
    + Keyword('of').suppress()
    + pp_identifier
    + Keyword('is').suppress()
    + Keyword('end')
    + Keyword('architecture')
    )

print(pp_architecture.parseString('''
architecture beh of sram is end architecture
''', parseAll=True))

# this works as I expected, it prints
# ['architecture', 'beh', 'sram', 'end', 'architecture']
```

But after changing `pp_architecture` to use `SkipTo` it fails:

```
pp_architecture = (
    Keyword('architecture')
    + pp_identifier
    + Keyword('of').suppress()
    + pp_identifier
    + Keyword('is').suppress()
    + pp.SkipTo(Keyword('end') + Keyword('architecture'))
    )

print(pp_architecture.parseString('''
architecture beh of sram is end architecture
''', parseAll=True))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1125, in parseString
    raise exc
pyparsing.ParseException: Expected end of text (at char 29), (line:2, col:29)
```

I also tried adding other text between `is` and `end` (which I expect to be skipped) to be sure it's not a problem of having an "empty skip", but that didn't help either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SkipTo` skips to the matching text, but by default does *not* parse that text. So you are advancing the parse location to 'end architecture', but not actually parsing it.

You can either:

1. add `Keyword('end') + Keyword('architecture')` after your `SkipTo` expression, or
2. pass `include=True` in the constructor of your `SkipTo` expression, telling it to skip to *and* parse the given strings.